# Go to file when file already open in other panes/windows open in Sublime 2

Tags: sublimetext2

If I have several panes (groups) open and do CTRL+P (go to anything) and type the name of a file which is already open in another pane, Sublime will open this file in the pane I started `Go to anything` from. I want it to go to any of the other panes, where this file is already opened instead of opening a new instance of the file.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of packages/plugins that may be close to what you want:

GotoOpenFile, you can choose from a list of views in whole window or the active group:
https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/GotoOpenFile

or the newer Zen Tabs, which has some other useful file status as well as tab management
https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Zen%20Tabs